# smb.conf allows Windows clients to access any component folder along the configured share path

Tags: samba

Below is the smb.conf used.

Windows clients are given access from “/” instead of  this path “/containers/rda-nas/OrbitalBackupRoot/PhantomCores/XXX” as the share’s root directory.

Could anyone point what configuration would disallow access to folders(component path) along the configured share path.

```
[rda-nas]
   path = /containers/rda-nas/OrbitalBackupRoot/PhantomCores/XXX
   browseable = no
   read only = no
   writable = yes
   include = /XXX/samba/rda-nas.inc
   force unknown acl user = yes
   ea support = yes
   strict sync = yes
   store dos attributes = yes
   follow symlinks = no
   mangled names = no
   nt acl support = yes
   smb encrypt = no
   oplocks = no
   level2 oplocks = no
   strict locking = no
   vfs object = streams_depot acl_xattr ocafs
   acl_xattr:ignore hashes = yes
   public = yes
```

One more question:

In NFS if we export a path, clients will never be known of parent directories along the export path. Why in samba, clients are shown and can traverse directories along the configured share path ?

Comment: What filesystem are you using? Do you have ACL support enabled for that filesystem?

Comment: It is a proprietary user-space filesystem (on top on underlying XFS filesystem). yes ACLs are supported and enabled.

Comment: I assume there's not more to your `smb.conf` which is allowing the "/" access?

Comment: Using ACL did you try denying the access the path where only special users are allowed? I think you have to do it that way. Or you need to define different shares with individual rights.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing.GerhardStein will try with ACL settings.

Comment: @RichardNixon there is no "/". Moreover, in NFS if we export a path, clients will never be known of parent directories along the export path. Why in samba, clients are shown and can traverse directories along the configured share path ?